# Почему отклонили мою правку из очереди проверок по причине "Её стоит опубликовать в форме комментария или ответа"?

Tags: обсуждение, правки, отклонённые-правки

Вопрос: [Функций событий столкновений: OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionEnter2D, OnCollisionStay, OnTriggerEnter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274786/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-oncollisionenter-oncollisionenter2d-oncollisions)

Отклоненная правка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/598457

Вопрос был задан по метке для "популярных и каноничных" вопросов: [unity3d-faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-faq). Он и вправду довольно важный в контексте метки [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) - по нему много вопросов, которые дубликатом закрыть сложно, потому что все они хоть и похожи, но отличаются на микроуровне конкретных ситуаций. Поэтому иметь одно место с общими ответами на такие вопросы важно, но так же важно максимально правильно ответить на эти вопросы.

Я нашел несколько неправильных пунктов, о чем вежливо уточнил в комментариях, один пункт автор вопроса исправил сам, другой попросил исправить лично меня, если у меня есть желание (между 1 и 2 комментарием вырезаны не относящиеся к этому посту комментарии):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

После чего 2 из 3 проверяющих отменили правку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С комментариями, вроде как, разобрались. На "отдельный ответ" моя правка тоже не тянет, и вот, почему:

Моя правка является компиляцией из небольших неточностей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, собственно, "отдельного ответа":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ответе, как я и говорил, были неправильные пункты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Описание которых выглядело бы криво/раздуто без ссылки на добавленную матрицу взаимодействия:

`"Объект с выключенным Rigidbody компонентом ведет себя как статический коллайдер, который отправляет событие столкновения только при столкновении с объектами с компонентом Rigidbody"`

вместо

`""Объект с выключенным Rigidbody компонентом ведет себя как статический коллайдер (см. Static Collider в матрице)"`

**P.S.** Да, в моей правке написано "считается" - это неверно, что я и хотел сегодня исправить.

Т.е. другие правки без матрицы не несли бы никакого смысла, их пришлось бы исправлять и раздувать большой ответ еще сильнее.

---

Пункт про комментарии я даже не воспринимаю, каким образом мне засунуть таблицы туда?

Добавлять ответ отдельно с этими правками? Так они же правки и ответом не являются.

Добавлять ответ отдельно с матрицами, которые в вакууме не отвечают на поставленный автором вопрос?

Добавлять свой ответ, который на 90% будет состоять информации в уже опубликованном ответе? А в чем смысл тогда для других пользователей, которым придется просканировать 2 огромные простыни на поиск малочисленных различий?

Answer (score 3):

Не стоит рассчитывать, что люди, проверяющие предлагаемые правки, будут анализировать её достаточно долго: например, читать предварительно переписку в комментариях под сообщением, вникать в суть задачи, а также ходить по ссылкам потенциальных дубликатов.

Если из простого взгляда на diff контента и прочтения комментария от автора правки правомочность правки будет не очевидна, то скорее всего такая правка будет отклонена.

Глядя на доступный [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/598457) diff, я тоже не вижу причин почему бы стоило эту правку принять.

Если есть какая-то договорённость с автором поста по правке, то у него есть полномочия утвердить в том числе и отклонённую на ревью правку. Т.о. если правка действительно не противоречит намерениям автора, стоит просто написать ему об этом в комментарии, и он её примет единолично.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда объясните, почему вы не видите причин для принятия правки. Помимо комментариев я привел и другие аргументы.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я говорю о решении исключительно по тому, на что обращают внимание в очереди проверок. Это сам diff и описание к нему. Всё. Допускаю, что всего лишь добавление фразы типа *"добавлено по просьбе автора поста"* в комментарий к правке привело бы к её принятию ревьюверами.